# How to make pattern of numbers in java using only two variables?

Tags: java

```
#1
#2 3
#4 5 6
#7 8 9 10
#11 12 13 14 15
```

this is the required pattern and the code which i used is

```
  public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int k = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
                System.out.print(k + " ");
                k++;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see i used the variable **k** to print the numbers.
My question is that is there a way to print the exact same pattern without using the third variable **k**?
I want to print the pattern using only **i** and **j**.

Comment: Hint: find a formula for calculating triangular numbers...

Comment: What's the point? Making the code more complex and less readable? less variables != better.

Comment: Note: you can do this with one variable if you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this problem is formulated as a learning exercise, I would not provide a complete solution, but rather a couple of hints:

- **Could you print the sequence if you knew the last number from the prior line?** - the answer is trivial: you would need to print `priorLine + j`
- **Given `i`, how would you find the value of the last number printed on `i-1` lines?** - to find the answer, look up the [formula for computing the sum of arithmetic sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum). In your case d=1 and a<sub>1</sub>=1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print((i * (i - 1)) / 2 + j + 1 + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can the find the nth term and subtract it each time:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(((i * (i + 1)) / 2) - (i - j) + " ");
           // k++;
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

You can use

```
System.out.println((i+j) + " ");
```

e.g.

```
i    j    (i+j)

0    1      1
1    1      2
2    1      3
2    2      4
..........
```